# Почему при нахождении сум в прямом и обратном порядке ответ разный?

Tags: c, циклы, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Почему при нахождении сумм в прямом (значение в переменной `s1`) и обратном порядке (`s2`) ответ разный?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float s1, s2; 
    long long int n;

    s1 = 0.; 
    for (n = 1; n <= 100000000; n++) s1 += 1. / (n * n);
    s2 = 0.; 
    for (n = 100000000; n >= 1; n--) s2 += 1. / (n * n);
    
    printf("%.17lf\n", s1); 
    printf("%.17lf\n\n", s2);
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "ответ разный" - в таких случаях следует указывать "разный ответ"

Comment: У float маленькая мантисса (где-то 6-7 десятичных цифр). Разное количество значащих цифр меняется в процессе округления при подсчете в разном порядке

Comment: @avp, вопрос в другом - кол-во циклов одинаковое же :)

Comment: @Zhihar, когда к уже накопленной сумме мы **(по одному)** добавляем маленькие числа, то они по сути отбрасываются. Если же сначала просуммировать маленькие, то какой-то их вклад останется.

Comment: avp, да, да, к этому и пришел, я просто подумал, что вы про точность как таковую говорите

Comment: О, классика! Еще в фиг каких времен "Кванте" с появлением первых калькуляторов этот вопрос рассматривался. Вы еще задумайтесь, какая сумма будет точнее — т.е. как лучше считать, от малых значений к большим или от больших к малым?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ситуация следующая (все как говорит @avp)
у float ограничена точность определённым кол-вом знаком после запятой, поэтому

```
1 + 10000000000000000000 = 10000000000000000000 (1e19)
```

точность у float в районе 7 знаков после запятой, поэтому у того же числа `10000000000000000000` в float входят только первые 7 цифр `1000000*************`, а остальные не влияют никак на число, т.е.

```
999999999999 + 10000000000000000000 = 10000000000000000000 (1e19)
```

теперь что делают 2 ваших цикла:

первый цикл начинает складывать от большего числа к меньшему, в какой-то момент уже не имеет значения, что вы складываете - это не повлияет на результат

для float в вашем коде после `n = 4096` все остальные слагаемые настолько малы относительно суммы, что не влияют на сумму

второй цикл начинает складывать от меньших чисел к большим, поэтому не учтенные в первом случае слагаемые после n = 4096 все таки в сумме образуют величину, которая влияет на итоговую сумму

поэтому и видим отличие

```
    s1  1.64472532  float
    s2  1.64493406  float
```

в первом случае поменьше, во втором побольше на ту самую сумму от `n = 4096` до `n = 100000000`, а на самом деле где-то до `n = 370728`

Кстати у `double` мантисса гораздо больше (весь тип занимает 8 байт вместо 4 для float), поэтому результаты тоже будут разными по описанным выше причинам, но отличаться будут на меньшую величину

```
    s1  1.6449340578345750  double
    s2  1.6449340568482265  double
```

и в первом цикле слагаемые не учитываются уже только с `n = 94906266`